# ORM for Image model

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm uncertain as to how a certain table should establish relationships, and I feel as if the solution I came up with is incorrect.

The `images` table is used to store an absolute path on a server (`path`). An image may belong to one of the following tables.

```
projects
comments
tickets
milestones
```

I decided that each image should have some nullable FKs to the respective relationships.

```
mysql> show columns in images;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| deleted_at   | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| path         | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| created_at   | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at   | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| project_id   | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| milestone_id | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| ticket_id    | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| comment_id   | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

However, this seems counterintuitive and ludicrous to query efficiently. I feel as thought it might be more appropriate to approach a Pivot schema wherein I have `images` with only the `path` and other boilerplate data, then have multiple Pivot tables representing the relationships (`many-to-many`).

```
projects_images
milestones_images
comments_images
ticket_images
```

Am I correct in assuming the Pivot schema is a better approach, or is there yet a better one out there?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table that contains images, you can hold the ImageID as a foreign key column in those tables:
projects_images
milestones_images
comments_images
ticket_images.
you asked for a "many to many" relationship solution but your design
looks like a "One to many" relationship  because you only got place for one integer in any of the cloumns you used for refefences(project_id ,milestone_id ,ticket_id ,comment_id).